# Is there a single-word/non-colloquialism antonym to the word "Exceeds" when it's used in its intransitive verb form?

Tags: word-request, verbs, antonyms

I'm looking for a single-word antonym for the word "exceeds" when it's being used without a subject. For example:

- "When the interest on a debt **exceeds** the holder's income, bankruptcy is inevitable."
- "Surely the man was insane. Like when a mad autocrat's reach **exceeds** his grasp, but none of his advisors dare speak up, he had begun operating in a vacuum."
- "Show only those results where the distance **exceeds** 5 miles"
- "Avoid committing to any lease where the term **exceeds** 48 months."

The problem is that when it's being used to describe a quantitative thing, the word appears to be unopposed by a *single-word* counterpart (much like "surpasses" or "transcends" or "surmounts", it occurs to me, now I start to write this question out):

"Where the distance __________ 5 miles."

> "is less than"
>
> "falls short of"
>
> "is shy of"

Am I just out of luck here? I ask because I'm a software engineer, I'm stuck working within a very finite amount of screen real estate, and I have asks from the client that I cannot sidestep:

[image: dropdown that only fits 7 or 8 characters or so]

I've never found myself wanting in the vocabulary department before, and I'm nearly convinced there is no such direct antonym, but I figure I'll pick the community's collective brain before going back to them and risk suffering the indignity of them off-the-cuffing a counterexample.

Comment: You could rewrite some of them. _Show only those distances less than 5 miles_

Comment: "Within" or "is within" may be suitable. *"Show only those [things] within 5 miles."*

Comment: Googling **exceeds antonym** indicates that no verb qualifies as such. You have to write around it in the manner that you have already illustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered "below"?

You could then change "exceeds" to "above" which saves you 2 characters of screen real estate.